# Bootstrap: baseline alignment of text input inside a table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with two columns, the first one is for labels, the other one mostly for texts but also for text inputs in some cases, like this:

```
<table>
    ...

    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
    </tr>

    ...
</table>
```

I want the "Name" label aligned with the baseline of the text input, however, when I do

```
td {
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

The result is:

[image: Baseline alignment not working]

See: http://jsfiddle.net/8tnqE/2/

I don't understand it. The text input has `vertical-align` set to `baseline` already, now my "label td" is aligned to baseline too and according to the spec, table cells with baseline alignments should align so that their baselines align. What is wrong?